# React Responsive Carousel how to change text font size shown in top right corner of image?

Tags: reactjs

In  `React Responsive Carousel` on top right corner it shows `1 of 3`

But the font is too small, is there a way to change it ?

**[Reference](https://morioh.com/p/e1effe342241)**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this in css

```
.carousel .carousel-status {
   font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: can you please share reference link for above answer ?